# how to get result using joins from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

how to get result from two tables using joins,one column from one table and one column count from another table in MySQL?

Comment: What do you mean by column count?  Can you provide an example of what the tables look like and what you want your result set to look like?

Comment: Come on, put a little effort into solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.Column1, t2.Column2
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

`table1.something, table2.somethingelse from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.tb1id`